# Terminator closes when right clicked, unfocused (clicked outside of window) and so on

Tags: ubuntu, terminator

I'm using terminator as my main terminal.

I've run into a problem where when I right-click the window, or click outside the window, the terminator window closes.
I have tried to purge, and reinstall. But the problem persists.

Kind regards - Chris

Comment: Isn't it hiding? I don't how terminator works, but for example with Guake it shows on pressing f12 and hides when not in focus.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

If I check htop, no current program is running.

Comment: Two of the answers below fixed it for me. One shows how to edit the config directly, one shows how to use the GUI.  I upvoted both as they both were helpful from different approaches. What's apparently a bug is that the setting for "hide on lose focus" setting makes it hidden completely when you simply try to click or type into the window. and hidden == no minimized icon, no hint on the desktop.

Answer (score 5):

Some days ago I had the same problem. Even cleaning up terminator folder and resinstalling it, just doens't work...

Today, I noticed it was a configured behavement, written on terminator config file.
So, you shold open it and clean 'focus' config line to let it default.

1. Open terminator config file:  `~/.config/terminator/config`
2. Check **[global_config]** lines, clean up any ***focus*** config line.
3. Open Terminator; Click with right mouse button (even terminator window closes); Click in *Preferences*, On the new windows opened, in **Global tab**, check if ***Mouse Focus*** option is setted to ***Click to focus**;* Close preferences window.
4. Open Terminator again and check if it's working fine!

Comment: For me it worked on setting `Mouse Focus` option to `GNOME Default`.

Comment: My terminator with checked 'Hide on lose focus' Global setting, will exists automatically. Uncheck it from Global setting page or remove focus related config from the config file works for me. FYI: terminator 2.1.1.

Answer (score 4):

A brief answer using GUI:

Right click to open "Preferences", and uncheck "Hide on lose focus" can solve this problem.

I noticed this after following the approach that @Mauricio provided.

Comment: Hi! This fixed it for me.  And by hide it meant the window goes away, no hint on the desktop where it is. apparently it was running in the background (could see the process was running via 'ps -a'). After a few days of putting this issue aside I can now go back to using my favorite terminal window!  Thanks!